# JOOQ - Java Math.max (x,y) equivalent

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I want to create a PostgreSQL query to update multiple columns (SMALLINT) with a lower boundary at zero. I'm thinking at the Java method Math.max(x,y). Something like `Math.max(columnValue, 0)`. There is the method `DSL.greatest(x,y)`, which seems to be perfect. But, this only accepts Field objects as parameters.

The example would be:

```
dslContext
  .update(TABLE)
  .set(TABLE.COLUMN1, DSL.greatest(TABLE.COLUMN1.minus(1), (short) 0))
  .set(TABLE.COLUMN2, DSL.greatest(TABLE.COLUMN2.minus(1), (short) 0))
  ... some more
  .where(TABLE.ID.eq(tableId))
  .execute();
```

This leads to compilation errors at the zeros.
Is it possible to create a Field object out of a number? Or how can I achieve this in any other another way?

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `DSL.inline()` to inline or `DSL.val()` to bind the variable.

```
dslContext
  .update(TABLE)
  .set(TABLE.COLUMN1, DSL.greatest(TABLE.COLUMN1.minus(1), DSL.inline((short) 0)))
  .set(TABLE.COLUMN2, DSL.greatest(TABLE.COLUMN2.minus(1), DSL.inline((short) 0)))
  ... some more
  .where(TABLE.ID.eq(tableId))
  .execute();
```